# pandas how to get row index satisfying certain condition in a vectorized way?

Tags: pandas

I have a timeseries dataframe containing market price and order information. For every entry, there is a stoploss accordingly. I want to find out the stoploss triggered bar index in the dataframe for each entry order. If the market **price >= stoploss** , then stop is triggered and I want to record that the stop belongs to which entry order. Each entry is recorded according to its entry **bar index**. For example, order with entry price 99 at bar 1 is recorded as entry order 1. Entry price 98 at bar 2 is entry order 2 and entry price 103 at bar 5 is entry order 5 etc.

The original dataframe is like:

```
    entry  price  index  entryprice  stoploss  
0       0    100      0         NaN       NaN   
1       1     99      1        99.0     102.0    
2       1     98      2        98.0     101.0    
3       0    100      3         NaN       NaN    
4       0    101      4         NaN       NaN   
5       1    103      5       103.0     106.0   
6       0    105      6         NaN       NaN    
7       0    104      7         NaN       NaN   
8       0    106      8         NaN       NaN   
9       1    103      9       103.0     106.0   
10      0    100     10         NaN       NaN    
11      0    104     11         NaN       NaN    
12      0    108     12         NaN       NaN    
13      0    110     13         NaN       NaN
```

code is :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'price':[100,99,98,100,101,103,105,104,106,103,100,104,108,110],
     'entry': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],})
df['index'] = df.index
df['entryprice'] = df['price'].where(df.entry==1)
df['stoploss'] = df['entryprice'] + 3
```

In order to find out where stoploss is triggered for each order, I do it in an apply way. I defined an outside parameter **stoplist** which is recording all the stoploss orders and their corresponding entry order index which are not triggered yet. Then I pass every row of the df to the function and compare the market price with the stoploss in the **stoplist**, whenever condition is met, assign the entry order index to this row and remove it from the **stoplist** variable.
The code is like:

```
def Stop(row, stoplist):
    output = None
    for i in range(len(stoplist)-1, -1, -1):
        (ix, stop) = stoplist[i]
        if row['price'] >= stop:
            output = ix
            stoplist.pop(i)

    if row['stoploss'] != None:
        stoplist.append( (row['index'], row['stoploss']) )

    return output

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'price':[100,99,98,100,101,103,105,104,106,103,100,104,108,110],
     'entry': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],})
df['index'] = df.index
df['entryprice'] = df['price'].where(df.entry==1)
df['stoploss'] = df['entryprice'] + 3
stoplist = []
df['stopix'] = df.apply(lambda row: Stop(row, stoplist), axis=1)
print(df)
```

The final output is:

```
    entry  price  index  entryprice  stoploss  stopix
0       0    100      0         NaN       NaN     NaN
1       1     99      1        99.0     102.0     NaN
2       1     98      2        98.0     101.0     NaN
3       0    100      3         NaN       NaN     NaN
4       0    101      4         NaN       NaN     2.0
5       1    103      5       103.0     106.0     1.0
6       0    105      6         NaN       NaN     NaN
7       0    104      7         NaN       NaN     NaN
8       0    106      8         NaN       NaN     5.0
9       1    103      9       103.0     106.0     NaN
10      0    100     10         NaN       NaN     NaN
11      0    104     11         NaN       NaN     NaN
12      0    108     12         NaN       NaN     9.0
13      0    110     13         NaN       NaN     NaN
```

The last column stopix is what I wanted. But the only problem of this solution is that apply is not very efficient and I am wondering if there is a **vectorized way** to do this? Or if there is any better solution boosting the performance would be helpful. Because efficiency is critical to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
# mark the block starting by entry
blocks = df.stoploss.notna().cumsum()

# mark where the prices are higher than or equal to entry price
higher = df['stoploss'].ffill().le(df.price)

# group higher by entries
g = higher.groupby(blocks)

# where the entry occurs in each group
idx = g.transform('idxmin')

# transform the idx to where the first higher occurs
df['stopix'] = np.where(g.cumsum().eq(1), idx, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    entry  price  index  entryprice  stoploss  stopix
0       0    100      0         NaN       NaN     NaN
1       1     99      1        99.0     102.0     NaN
2       1     98      2        98.0     101.0     NaN
3       0    100      3         NaN       NaN     NaN
4       0    101      4         NaN       NaN     2.0
5       1    103      5       103.0     106.0     NaN
6       0    105      6         NaN       NaN     NaN
7       0    104      7         NaN       NaN     NaN
8       0    106      8         NaN       NaN     5.0
9       1    103      9       103.0     106.0     NaN
10      0    100     10         NaN       NaN     NaN
11      0    104     11         NaN       NaN     NaN
12      0    108     12         NaN       NaN     9.0
13      0    110     13         NaN       NaN     NaN
```